# Proof of the cardinality of continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces

I've been thinking about the cardinality of continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$. I know that the cardinality is the same as that of $[0,1]$ and the standard proof using the fact that such a function is determined by its values on the rational numbers but I had another proof idea.

The set $F = \{f| f: [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1] \ \text{ and is continuous}\} \subset  G =\{g| g: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \ \text{and is continuous}\}$ which is an infinite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ and has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$ which has the same cardinality as $[0,1]$. So $F \leq [0,1]$. Also, $[0,1] \leq F$ because we can map $p \in [0,1]$ to the constant function $f(x) = p$. The Schroeder-Bernstein theorem implies that $|F| = |[0,1]|$

Is this a correct alternative or a disguised variation of the standard proof?

Comment: Why does $|G|=|\mathbb{R}|$ for purposes of your proof? Note that $|\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}| \geq |2^{\mathbb{R}}| > |\mathbb{R}|$, so you are indeed excluding many functions by restricting to the continuous ones.

Comment: Abraham: There is definitely a gap there, where you assumed something practically equivalent to what you want to prove.  Are you saying that being an infinite dimensional vector space has something to do with it? How exactly?

Comment: I think I'm under the impression or recall reading somewhere that the space of all continuous functions is an infinite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ isomorphic to the infinite dimensional Euclidean space which has the same cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$ and because $F$ is a subset of the space of all continuous functions $|F| \leq |\mathbb{R}|$.

Comment: "infinite dimensional Euclidean space"--meaning what, exactly? $\ell^2$?  And whatever it means, how do you prove that its cardinality is the same as that of $\mathbb R$, or that it is isomorphic to $C[0,1]$ (and in what way do you mean isomorphic)?

Comment: The question you would need to answer is: how do you find the dimension of the continuous functions as a vector space over $\Bbb R$?  How do you know that this dimension is $|\Bbb N|$ rather than $|\Bbb R|$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom.  The dimension is $|\mathbb R|$

Comment: @JonasMeyer doesn't the existence of an injective transformation from this space to $\Bbb R^{\Bbb Q}$ imply that the dimension is $|\Bbb Q| = |\Bbb N|$, or am I missing something?  Perhaps I should specify the dimension with respect to a [Schauder basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: You wrote: "the dimension of continuous functions as a vector space over $\mathbb R$"-- and that is what I took you to mean.  Based on your last comment, apparently not.  The vector space $\mathbb R^{\mathbb Q}$ has dimension $|\mathbb R|$.  For dimension $|\mathbb N|$, you would want a direct sum rather than direct product.  But now I suppose you knew this and were talking about something else.

Comment: @JonasMeyer sorry for the confusion; I was a bit careless when making my original comment